# symfony2 doctrine updating entities generates a .php file in entity directory

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I run this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundleName
```

All the setters and getters are generated correctly, except that it generates a .php file in my Entity directory

[image]

with the following content

```
<?php

namespace Goodeed\BEBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * 
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class  extends EntityRepository
{
}
```

So if I run for example

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get this error:

[image]

I don't really care about the error because when I delete the file everything works as expected and no more errors arise. So my question is, what could cause the generation of this .php file?

Answer (score 0):

My hypothesis would be that there is this kind of annotation in your Entity :

```
 @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourBundle\Entity\ ")
```

With this annotation, the command you prompted has this behaviour.

Hope this helps.